# Sporadic timeouts from directline endpoint

Tags: networking, botframework

We have deployed a simple Echobot using the Azure template when creating a Web App Bot.

It is currently live at this url: http://18.194.88.194/echobot/

We often experience the following timeout error (about 40% of the time)

> WebSocket connection to
>   'wss://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/EH9EbbBIasz8o90sZSeAwT-9/stream?watermark=-&t=ew0KICAiYWxnIj...(snip)
>   failed: Error in connection establishment:
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Here is our client code:
`botclient.js`

```
(async function() {
  let {token, conversationId} = sessionStorage;

  const delay = 1800000;
  //const delay = 20000;
  const currentTime = new Date();
  const currentTimeUnix = currentTime.getTime();

  if (
    sessionStorage['startTime'] &&
    currentTimeUnix - sessionStorage['startTime'] > delay
  ) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
    token = sessionStorage['token'];
  }

  const payload = JSON.stringify({botname: 'echobot'});

  if (!token) {
    const res = await fetch(
      'https://ox38xh0fx5.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/directline/token',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: payload,
      },
    );
    const {token: directLineToken} = await res.json();
    sessionStorage['token'] = directLineToken;
    token = directLineToken;

    console.log('token', token);
    const startTime = new Date();
    const startTimeUnix = startTime.getTime();
    sessionStorage['startTime'] = startTimeUnix;
  }

  const data = {
    // from: user,
    name: 'requestWelcomeDialog',
    type: 'event',
    value: {
      url: window.location.href,
    },
  };

  var botConnection = new window.WebChat.createDirectLine({token});

  window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
    {
      directLine: botConnection,
      userID: 'YOUR_USER_ID',
      username: 'Web Chat User',
      locale: 'en-US',
    },
    document.getElementById('webchat'),
  );
})().catch(err => console.log(err));
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
      <style>
         html,
         body {
            height: 100%;
         }

         body {
            margin: 0;
         }

         #webchat {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
      <script src="botclient.js">
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

The token is being retrieved from an AWS lambda function with the following code:

```
import json
import boto3
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen


BOT_SECRET = 'defaultSecret'


URL = 'https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate'
POST_FIELDS = {'foo': 'bar'}


def set_headers(req, secret):
    req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    req.add_header('Authorization', f'Bearer {secret}')
    return req


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    if event.get('botname', None) == 'echobot':
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket='directline', Key='echobotSecret')
    else:
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket='directline', Key=BOT_SECRET)
    secret = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
    request = Request(URL, urlencode(POST_FIELDS).encode())
    request = set_headers(request, secret)
    jsonresponse = urlopen(request).read()

    print(jsonresponse)
    return jsonresponse
```

We suspect that there is an issue with the local network configuration, and packets are being dropped. Are there any pointers for how to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked into our backend logs for the conversation ID you included and it looks like the token needs to be refreshed. See [the Authentication docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#refresh-token) for refreshing tokens.

It looks like your code attempts to account for token expiration, but:

- 1800000 is the default expiration. It might be best to shorten your delay a bit to account for request travel time and other factors to ensure your tokens don't expire.
- You appear to only get the token once, when the chat window is opened. It may expire mid-conversation

---

That being said, this may not be a token issue. Can you try disabling websockets with:

```js
[...]
window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
    {
      directLine: botConnection,
      userID: 'YOUR_USER_ID',
      username: 'Web Chat User',
      locale: 'en-US',
      webSocket: false // ADD THIS !!!!
    },
    document.getElementById('webchat'),
[...]
```

---

If this *is* a local packet loss issue, I'm afraid there's not much support I can provide as it's no longer a botframework problem and is likely very specific to your local network. If you can provide additional Conversation IDs, I might be able to dig into this further. But over the last 2 days, your bot appears pretty normal on our side.